# Adding a Time to a DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a calendar and a textbox that contains a time of day. I want to create a datetime that is the combination of the two. I know I can do it by looking at the hours and mintues and then adding these to the calendar DateTime, but this seems rather messy.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You can use the [DateTime.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.add.aspx)() method to add the time to the date.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan(36, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime combined = date.Add(time);
Console.WriteLine("{0:dddd}", combined);
```

You can also create your timespan by [parsing a String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9.aspx), if that is what you need to do.

Alternatively, you could look at using other controls. You didn't mention if you are using winforms, wpf or asp.net, but there are various date and time picker controls that support selection of both date and time.

Comment: after hours i tried for `11:57 pm` and this worked:

`TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan(23, 57, 00);
               DateTime date_with_time = mydate.Add(time);`

Comment: If you're ever in the situation where you have a specific amount of time (eg: X hours or Y minutes) there are helper functions so that you don't have to create a TimeSpan().  eg: ```DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(10);``` // a time 10 seconds in the future!

Comment: @SeanColombo what about current Time that get using ToShortTimeString() ??

Answer (score 23):

If you are using two DateTime objects, one to store the date the other the time, you could do the following:

```
var date = new DateTime(2016,6,28);

var time = new DateTime(1,1,1,13,13,13);

var combinedDateTime = date.AddTicks(time.TimeOfDay.Ticks);
```

An example of this can be found [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/V2pw7C)

Comment: Just what I was looking for

Comment: But why not `date.Add(time.TimeOfDay)` ?

Answer (score 5):

Depending on how you format (and validate!) the date entered in the textbox, you can do this:

```
TimeSpan time;

if (TimeSpan.TryParse(textboxTime.Text, out time))
{
   // calendarDate is the DateTime value of the calendar control
   calendarDate = calendarDate.Add(time);
}
else
{
   // notify user about wrong date format
}
```

Note that [TimeSpan.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z48198e.aspx) expects the string to be in the 'hh:mm' format (optional seconds).

Answer (score 3):

Using https://github.com/FluentDateTime/FluentDateTime

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime combined = dateTime + 36.Hours();
Console.WriteLine(combined);
```

Comment: I love FuentDateTime. If this is the only datetime sum you want to do then it might not be worth it. But, there's a lot of other great stuff in there like finding out when the next Friday is.

Comment: @RichardGarside: Do you mean the FluentDateTime NuGet package from the [GitHub](https://github.com/FluentDateTime)?

Comment: It is available as a Nuget package. There are links on the Github page.

Answer (score 1):

```
   DateTime newDateTime = dtReceived.Value.Date.Add(TimeSpan.Parse(dtReceivedTime.Value.ToShortTimeString()));
```

Comment: Although this is is a correct answer, you should provide an explanation to OP instead of providing a code only answer to make sure they (and any other views) understand why the answer is correct..

Answer (score 0):

Combine both. The Date-Time-Picker does support picking time, too.

You just have to change the Format-Property and maybe the CustomFormat-Property.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but figured I'd share my solution, I'm using separate date and time picker controls so I needed to use just the date from one control and just the time from another control which both use . This would work equally as well with time in a textbox though you should probably use a masked textbox or some kind of validation on the text input.

I'm using telerik controls, but you get the idea and it will work the same with any DateTime objects:

```
var startDateTime = DateTime.Parse($"{dateStart.Value.Date.ToShortDateString()} {tpStart.Value.Value.ToShortTimeString()}");
```

or if using a textbox for time:

```
var startDateTime = DateTime.Parse($"{dateStart.Value.Date.ToShortDateString()} {txtTime.Text}");
```