# How to add a 12 hour string to datetime

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I have a datetime object with the date in it, but no time.

I have a string that has the 12 hours (ex. "6:00 AM", "10:00 AM", "4:00 PM", "11:00 PM")
How can I add this time to the date time variable?

Comment: So, what do you want? You want to add 6, 10,16, or 23 hours to your datetime object?

Comment: You can probably parse your 12 hour string into a `TimeSpan` then use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146296/adding-a-time-to-a-datetime-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
var datetime = DateTime.Now;        
var newDateTime = datetime.AddHours(DateTime.Parse("6:00 PM").Hour);
```